# Find out which scripts are calling a perl package

Tags: perl

I’m not a perl programmer so sorry if this is obvious. There is a perl package on a system I am working on that I want to modify, but I don’t know which other programs are using it. I can tell that at least three cron jobs use it because I put these lines into the file:

```
open(STDOUT, '>', "/var/log/SS_logs/packageAlert.log");
open(STDERR, '>', "/var/log/SS_logs/packageAlert.error.log");

print "\nThe program packageAlert.pm  is running on " . `date` . "\n";
```

and 10 minutes later I got three lines in my log. There may be more that call it on a daily or weekly basis and it could be called in web pages as well.

I searched for occurrences of the package with **grep -R "SS::alert" .** so know that there are 20 or so scripts and web pages that may use the package.

Is there a function that I can call to find out which file called the package?

Comment: Replacing the print with `use Carp qw( cluck ); cluck(__PACKAGE__ . " loaded");` to get a stack backtrace, all the way up to the script.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. The calling files show up in my error.log file.

Answer (score 3):

The [caller](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller) function can tell you the file that called you (this is the same thing that lets modulinos work).

```
use v5.10;
say "Loading " . __FILE__ . " at " . localtime();

use File::Spec::Functions qw(rel2abs);
my $calling_file = rel2abs( (caller(0))[1] );

say "Loaded by $calling_file";
1;
```